# Wix: conditionally adding files at build time

Tags: include, wix

Hi
I'm in a situation where **I need to include bunch of files conditionally at Build Time**.

I need some tips to use Pre-Processor variables to set a particular group of files to be included in the installer at Build Time.

I experimented with `<? include Group1.wxi ?>` while defining like folloiwng:

```
<Include>
  <DirectoryRef Id="PLANTROOT">
    <!--Adding Plugins======= Start ==-->
    <Directory Id="Plugins" Name="Plugins">
      <Directory Id="PIW_Plugin" Name="PIW">
        <Merge Id='PIWtoIDGNConverter' Language='0' SourceFile='PIWtoIDGNConverter.msm' FileCompression='yes' DiskId='1' />
        <Directory Id="Dir_ECFramework" Name="ECFramework" >
          <Merge Id='ECFrameworkMergeModule' Language='0' SourceFile='ECFrameworkMergeModule.msm' FileCompression='yes' DiskId='1' />
    </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <!--Adding Plugins=======Stop==-->
  </DirectoryRef>

<FeatureRef Id="PIWMain">
    <!--Sub Feature for PIW 2 IDGN Converter Plugin-->
    <Feature Id="PIW_imodel_OWL_Plugin" AllowAdvertise="no" Description="PIW i-model &amp; OWL" Display="expand" Level="1" Title="PIW i-model &amp; OWL" InstallDefault="followParent">
      <MergeRef Id='PIWtoIDGNConverter' />
      <MergeRef Id='ECFrameworkMergeModule' />
      <MergeRef Id='ECObjectsMergeModule' />
      <MergeRef Id='PlatformSdkBinariesMergeModule'  />
      <!-- <MergeRef Id='ECFW_LicenseClient'  /> -->
      <MergeRef Id='ManagedLogClientMergeModule'  />
      <MergeRef Id='ECClassEditor'  />
      <MergeRef Id='ClassEditorRDSPlugin'  />
      <MergeRef Id='SQLDbECPluginMergeModule'  />
      <MergeRef Id='SQLDbECCEExtensionMergeModule'  />
    </Feature>
  </FeatureRef>
```

That is, referencing the Directory and Feature in Parent file. But wxi is not accepting DirectoryRef and FeatureRef

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid Includes completely in this case. Instead, create your Files and Components and group them in ComponentGroups in separate Fragments. Then in your Feature(s) conditionally include ComponentGroupRefs. For example, let's say you have a files.wxs like (imagine more files ;):

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="Foo">
    <Component Directory="DirectoryId">
       <File Source="path\to\file.ext"/>
    </Component>
  </Component>
</Fragment>
```

Then in product.wxs:

```
<Product ...>
  <Feature Id="F">
    <?ifdef IncludeFiles ?>
       <ComponentGroupRef Id="Foo" />
    <?endif?>
  </Feature>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I was adding the include file at wrong place. Was confused of Fragments and file was being included after  where only  should reside with references.